# When web scraping, I am getting different data in the the Network/Response tab than when I open the link in a new tab

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape Fliff (a sportsbook) to get all of the matchups and odds. For sportsbooks that I have been successful at scraping, I have gotten a link for all of the data in the Inspect Element -> Network and then doing a `requests.get(url).json()` in python. I have found the link I need for Fliff, and I can view the contents in the 'Preview' section in Chrome, but when I open the link in a new tab, I get the message 'nothing to see here move along', which I assume is a 403 error. The same happens when I try to access it with python.

[image: Here is what I see:]

Fliff is only accessible from a mobile device, so I have tried switching the User agent to a mobile device, but it still doesn't work. Interestingly, I can access the data from the link Firefox. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a common question for people trying to scrape data from a web site, but not something we can help with. The site is clearly defending against scraping. They'll be looking at the sequence of requests, cookies submitted, user-agent string and other data. This is easily done in a browser, but unless you match the requirements accurately you'll just get a 403 error. Every site's requirement is different. You'll need to reverse engineer the call sequence. This is not something we can help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing copy as curl [image: copy as curl].

Then use curl converter like this one https://curlconverter.com/python/ to convert that to python code.

The curl call will have your platform, cookies and other things. This should fix the problem.